# How to know if audio is going dead in Naudio C#`

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to find out when the song is going dead (inaudible sound for few seconds). I am using Naudio library in C#. Till now i am able to get the PCM data and plot the amplitude of the audio. I am guessing the dead audio through this amplitude i am obtaining. But i am bit confused about audio channels. Following is the piece of code i wrote.

```
        NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 wave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(open.FileName));

        int songLength = (int)wave.Length;
        byte[] songPCM = new byte[songLength];

        int sampleRate = (int)wave.WaveFormat.SampleRate;
        int bitsPerSample = (int)wave.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample;
        int numChannels = (int)wave.WaveFormat.Channels;

        wave.Read(songPCM, 0, songLength);


        double[] _waveLeft = new double[songLength / 8];
        double[] _waveRight = new double[songLength / 8];


        System.IO.StreamWriter fileoutLeft = new System.IO.StreamWriter("E:\\LOutputSongPCM.dat", true);
        System.IO.StreamWriter fileoutRight = new System.IO.StreamWriter("E:\\ROutputSongPCM.dat", true);


            int h = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < songLength; i += 8)
            {

                _waveLeft[h] = (double)BitConverter.ToSingle(songPCM, i);
                _waveRight[h] = (double)BitConverter.ToSingle(songPCM, i + 4);

                chart1.Series["wave"].Points.Add(_waveLeft[h]);
                //chart1.Series["wave"].Points.Add(_waveRight[h]);

                fileoutLeft.WriteLine(_waveLeft[h]);
                fileoutRight.WriteLine(_waveRight[h]);
                h++;
            }

            fileoutLeft.Close();
            fileoutRight.Close();
```

Now for this piece of code i know the audio is 2 channel. So i referred many links and threads and got confused if i am reading my pcm data for each channel correctly. However i compared the plots of each channel and they look good(Matching with original song) but i am not sure about their accuracy. Can you guide me to get the exact raw data for any channel. for mono, stereo and 5.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find it easier to get at the samples by using the `AudioFileReader` class, whose `Read` method takes a float array. The samples are stored interleaved for multi-channel audio, so for stereo, you'll get left sample, then right sample, then another left and so on.